# How to get some data after click on certain item RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have already seen a lot of material on this subject even here, namely the list of individual elements of the list. My application receives from the server two lists of messages, incoming and outgoing. And when you click on one of these two lists, you need to switch to the activation, which contains the selected message. When you press it, you need to somehow pull it out the way we said and throw this id into the query. I currently have such an adapter for `RecyclerView`:

```
package com.example.developer_4.test_login.Tabs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.developer_4.test_login.R;
import com.example.developer_4.test_login.data.model.Message;

import java.util.List;

class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewItemClickListener;
    private List<Message> messageList;
    private Context ctx;



    MessageAdapter(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messageList.get(position);
        String id = String.valueOf(message.getId());
        holder.subject.setText(message.getSubject());
        holder.from.setText(message.getSender_name());
        holder.date.setText(message.getDate());


        holder.getAdapterPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView from, subject, date;
        int position = 0;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            subject = v.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            from = v.findViewById(R.id.from);
            date = v.findViewById(R.id.date);
            //id = v.findViewById(R.id.id);


            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

at the moment I have hung on a click on the message element sending a request with the id of the message that I entered manually, I have a function getId in the response class from the server, that is, I can get this id, but I do not understand how to catch clicking on a separate list item . I've seen ways to use position but I somehow did not get accustomed to them)) after clicking on a certain element of this list, I need to pass on to another activity of the id of the message by which we clicked in the list, in order to display this message on the other screen.

Thank you all for valuable advice, answers and criticism)). Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

Comment: Just create your own interface RecyclerViewClickListener and send to it all that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can add data by adding tag to any view in your `onBindViewHolder` method.

```
holder.itemView.setTag("Some Data");
```

And then get that tag when clicked.

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       String someData=(String)view.getTag();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try setting :

```
holder.setTag(position);
```

then

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        int pos = (int)view.getTag();
        Message message = messageList.get(pos);
      }
});
```